# ¿Cómo filtrar observaciones que en su conjunto cumplen con un determinado criterio?

Tags: r

Llevo bastante pensando en el siguiente problema y no soy experto en R así que aún hallo una solución. Tengo el siguiente `data.frame` (el original es bastante más grande y con mas campos, pero resumo los de interés):

```
df<-data.frame(c(2010, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2012), c(rep("A",5),rep("B",3),rep("C",4)),c(1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,1))
```

dónde `2010`, `2011`, `2012` son los años que estoy analizando; `A`, `B`, `C` hace referencia a 3 colegios diferentes y la tercera columna corresponde al alumno de ese colegio en ese año:

```
   year colegio alumno
1  2010       A      1
2  2010       A      2
3  2011       A      1
4  2012       A      1
5  2012       A      2
6  2010       B      1
7  2010       B      2
8  2011       B      1
9  2010       C      1
10 2011       C      2
11 2011       C      2
12 2012       C      1
```

El colegio `B` solo aparece en los años `2010` y `2011` pero no en el `2012`. Quiero hacer un nuevo `data.frame` que sea un subset únicamente de los colegios que aparecen en todos los años considerados: es decir algo así:

```
  year colegio alumno
1 2010       A      1
2 2010       A      2
3 2011       A      1
4 2012       A      1
5 2012       A      2
6 2010       C      1
7 2011       C      2
8 2011       C      2
9 2012       C      1
```

Considerando que la base completa contiene alrededor de 2000 colegios no sé cuales de ellos están en todos los años o no, de tal manera que el código debe identificar cuales son esos colegios que no se repiten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otra alternativa es usar `dplyr`, no soy original en decir que la sintaxis es sumamente clara.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    inner_join(df %>%
                   group_by(colegio) %>%
                   summarize(cant = n_distinct(year)) %>%
                   filter(cant == max(cant))
    )
```

Al `data.frame` original le hacemos un `inner join` contra una versión de si mismo agrupada por colegio y filtrada por aquellos colegios cuya cantidad de años sea igual a la del colegio con la mayor cantidad.

Comment: Probaré tambien esta alternativa. Ultimamente he encontrado muchas soluciones usando dplyr. Gracias por la respuesta

Comment: muchas gracias Patricio, al parecer el método usando inner join funciona a la perfección. Considerando en uso que le voy a dar a los datos y la cantidad, la revisión detallada del resultado me ha tomado algo de tiempo, pero hasta donde voy todo va perfecto. Nuevamente, gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Primero armamos tu `data.frame` de ejemplo:

```
df<-data.frame(year=c(2010, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2012), 
               colegio=c(rep("A",5),rep("B",3),rep("C",4)),
               alumno=c(1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,1))
```

Bien, una forma usando R base es la siguiente:

```
colegio <- aggregate(year ~ colegio, df, function(x) {length(unique(x))})
df[df$colegio %in% as.character(colegio[colegio$year == max(colegio$year),1]),]

  year colegio alumno
1  2010       A      1
2  2010       A      2
3  2011       A      1
4  2012       A      1
5  2012       A      2
9  2010       C      1
10 2011       C      2
11 2011       C      2
12 2012       C      1
```

- Con `aggregate(year ~ colegio, df, function(x) {length(unique(x))})` generamos un `data.frame` con cada colegio y la cantidad de años que tienen registrados
- Luego, usamos esos datos para quedarnos únicamente con aquellas filas cuyos colegios tengan la máxima cantidad de años: `df[df$colegio %in% as.character(colegio[colegio$year == max(colegio$year),1]),]`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta y la explicación. Lo estuve probando con la base de datos completa y no me funciona, aunque tampoco genera ningun error. Detecto que no funciona porque las dimensiones (las filas) del data frame no cambian. Creo que debo hacer una revisión de los datos de mi data frame porque con el ejemplo que puse funciona perfectamente.

Comment: @jgaitan, si estás usando el código de mi respuesta revisa haciendo `unique(colegio$year)`, si solo obtienes un número, lo que ocurre es que todos los colegios tienen la misma cantidad de años, tal vez no sean los mismos años, pero la muestra tiene la misma cantidad de estos.

Comment: Seguí lo que me indicas y no todos tienen la misma cantidad de años. Tambien revisé un poco la estructura y una muestra pequeña de la información y hay colegios que están en diferentes numeros de años. Estive revisando el tipo de datos y el campo año no es una fecha, está como texto, no sé si esto influya el resultado.